# Are all linear vector fields geodesible vector fields?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

I had already asked this [question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408030/is-a-linear-vector-field-a-geodesible-vector-field) then I ask here at MO.

Assume that $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a  non singular matrix.

> Is the flow of the linear vector field  $X'=AX$ a geodesible flow on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$? Namely, is there a Riemannian metric on   $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$
> such that the trajectories of the linear vector field are unparametrized geodesics?

**Remark:** For $n=2$ the answer is affirmative, as we explain below:

**Fact:**  A linear vector field associated to a non singular $2 \times 2$ real matrix is a geodesible vector field on the punctured plane.

**Proof:**

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. We denote by $X$ the linear vector field associated to $A$.

We consider two cases:

1. $A^2$ has no real eigenvalue.
2. $A^2$ has a real eigenvalue.

Case 1) In this case the linear vector field $Y$ associated to the matrix $A^{-1}$ is transverse to $X$ on the punctured plane and satisfies $[X,Y]=0$.  This obviously implies that $X$ is a geodesible vector field.

Case 2) If $A^2$ has a real eigenvalue then $A$ is similar to one of the following matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\ 0& b \end{pmatrix};\; \begin{pmatrix} a&\epsilon\\ 0& a \end{pmatrix} ;\;\begin{pmatrix} 0&b\\ -b& 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
For the first matrix the closed $1$-form $\psi=ax\,dx+by\,dy$ satisfies $\psi(X)>0$.  So $X$ is a geodesible vector field.  For the second matrix the $1$-form $\psi=ax\,dx+ay\,dy$ satisfies $\psi(X)>0$. For the third matrix the vector field is geodesible because we have a foliation of the punctured plane by closed curves.

The reason of geodesibility of case 1 and the three matrices in case 2 is discussed in
[Finding a 1-form adapted to a smooth flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648), which is essentially based on page 71 of "Geometry of foliation " by Philip Toender, Propsitions 6.7 and 6.8.

Please see also the related post [Is every real matrix conjugate to a semi antisymmetric matrix?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282694/is-every-real-matrix-conjugate-to-a-semi-antisymmetric-matrix).